# "Наивысочайший"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попалось в тексте слово "наивысочайший". Так, вообще, можно сказать или получается уже тавтология?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая форма превосходной степени сравнения образуется при помощи суффиксов -айш- и -ейш-. Превосходная степень прилагательного **высокий** - *высочайший*. В книжном стиле простая форма превосходной степени может осложняться приставкой наи-, которая усиливает степень проявления признака, например: *наипростейший, наидобрейший, наилегчайший*. (Большой лингвистический словарь В.Д.Стариченка). Следовательно, слово **наивысочайший** имеет право на существование. Но его употребление ограничено книжным стилем.